# Using VSTS to publish Azure Function to Zip file

Tags: msbuild, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

I am trying to use VSTS to publish a project that contains an Azure Function. My MSBuild step is passing the following build arguments

> /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true
>   /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true
>   /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true
>   /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\MyFunctions.$(Build.BuildNumber)-dev.zip"
>   /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"

This is giving me a Zip where the folder structure of ***\Content\D_C\a\3\s\MyFunctions\obj\Release\net461\PubTmp\Out***. The Out directory has the content I need and what I'd expect to be the root

The folder structure I need to push a Zip is

[image]

As documented [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push)

Can anyone advise on what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to push it ? there is nothing wrong with your package, you shouldn't care about the VSTS path

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do it in a 2 step process

1. build with a VSTS Build task with settings `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeployTarget=Package;CreatePackageOnPublish=true`
2. ZIP it with a VSTS Archive Files task. Here I leave the option to `Prefix root folder name...` unchecked.

Sample:
[image: sample Archive files task]

Comment: This method generated exactly the same zip file as the question-poster

Answer (score 0):

With **Azure App Service Deploy** task and **Publish using Web Deploy** option, it won’t remain the folder structure and the content files will be in **wwwroot folder** of azure app service. So you don’t need to care the package folder structure.

Otherwise, you can publish the app through FileSystem publish method (e.g. `/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishUrl="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\" /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish`), then zip files through **Archive files** task, after that you can deploy it through Zip push deployment way (Azure CLI or PowerShell)

[Zip push deployment for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push)